# How do I set the target of a UIRefreshControl in Xcode Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, swift

This code:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, 
    action: Selector("refreshTable"), 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

How do I do this graphically in Xcode 6's Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried control-dragging from the control to the view controller? First set up the handler

```
@IBAction func refreshTable {
   // refresh the table
}
```

Comment: Sometimes dragging does not work from the diagram - do it from the outline view.